# C# Searching through one list and sending information to another list

Tags: c#, json, list, foreach

I have "Search by surname", where problem is: I have to search by surname in Klijent list -> get OIB from Klijent list that matches that surname (there could be few people with same surname and different "OIB - personal identification number") -> send OIB to PoliceOsiguranja list -> print out that/those policies which are assigned to OIB.

Again, OIB is the only thing that is connecting PoliceOsiguranja and Klijent lists.

I will insert code, but that code was designed for something bit different where datas are stored in Klijent and in PoliceOsiguranja.

```
                Console.WriteLine("Search by surname (2)");
                Console.WriteLine("Input surname (prezime):");
                string pPrezime = Console.ReadLine();
                List<PoliceOsiguranja> lPoliceOsiguranja = DohvatiPoliceOsiguranja();
                List<Klijent> lKlijent = DohvatiKlijente();
                int RedniBr = 1;
                    long pomocniOIB = 0;

                    foreach (var Klijent in lKlijent)
                    {
                        if (Klijent.prezime == pPrezime)
                        {
                            nPomocna = 1;
                            pomocniOIB = Klijent.OIB;
                            Console.WriteLine("Client by OIB: " + Klijent.OIB + " - " + Klijent.ime + " " + Klijent.prezime + " " + Klijent.grad);
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Created insurance policies:");
                    var tablica = new ConsoleTable("Order number (RedniBr). ", "Policy number", "Type of insurance", "Date", "Date", "Value");
                    foreach (var PoliceOsiguranja in lPoliceOsiguranja)
                    {
                        if (PoliceOsiguranja.OIB == pomocniOIB)
                        {
                            nPomocna = 1;
                            tablica.AddRow(RedniBr++ + ".", PoliceOsiguranja.BrojPolice, PoliceOsiguranja.VrstaOsiguranja, PoliceOsiguranja.DatumPocetka, PoliceOsiguranja.DatumIsteka, PoliceOsiguranja.Vrijednost);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: _but that code was designed for something bit different_ Could you please share the actual sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood correctly what you are asking :

1 - Get oib list that match pPrezime name

```
IEnumerable<long> oibList = lKlijent
    .Where(lk => lk.Prezime.Equals(pPrezime, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .Select(o => o.OIB);
```

2 - Print out policies

```
foreach (PoliceOsiguranja policeOsiguranja in lPoliceOsiguranja)
{
   if (oibList.Contains(policeOsiguranja.OIB))
   {
       nPomocna = 1;
       tablica.AddRow(RedniBr++ +".", policeOsiguranja.BrojPolice, 
       policeOsiguranja.VrstaOsiguranja, policeOsiguranja.DatumPocetka, 
       policeOsiguranja.DatumIsteka, policeOsiguranja.Vrijednost);
   }
 }
```